# CSS Positioning 70-30 with Inline-Block

Tags: css

I am positioning `main-bar` and `side-bar` with `70-30` ratio as under: [***JSFIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/a7rkqdsp/)

```css
.main-bar, .side-bar{
 position: relative;
 margin:0; padding: 0;
 outline: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 border:none;
    background:#CCC
}
.main-bar{width: 70%}
.side-bar{width: 30%}

/* This Works

.side-bar{width: 29%}

*/
```

```html
<div class="main-bar">
    I am the King!
</div>

<div class="side-bar">
   I am not less!
</div>
```

Interestingly, it works with `70-29` ratio. Did I miss something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove **white space** between divs as it also take place and doesn't let **inline-blocks** align properly.

```css
.main-bar, .side-bar {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    background: #CCC;
}
.main-bar {
    width: 70%;
}
.side-bar {
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-bar">
    I am the King!
</div><!--

--><div class="side-bar">
   I am not less!
</div>
```

Reference: [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: WOW! Never notices that. I thought White Spaces were neglected in HTML. @emmanuel Is there a CSS Way of saying, neglect them because commenting this way may sometimes be problem while fetching from database or something. And the code doesnot look smart as well

Comment: You could try **font-size: 0** or **negative margin** method, please check reference url.

Comment: @selu this question adresses ways to remove the white-space : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 2):

This is because the white space in-between your inline-block elements you need make them `0` using the `font-size` property just as follows

```
body{
    font-size: 0;
}
.main-bar, .side-bar{
    position: relative;
    margin:0; padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    border:none;
    background:#CCC
}
.main-bar{width: 70%}
.side-bar{width: 30%}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8p07y6pz/)

Comment: Any cross cons or problems of this approach. @Benjamin It looks good but not sure if that is safe. What is the technical meaning of `font-size:0`?

Comment: it is not nescessary that you need to give the body `font-size: 0;` you can just use it for you inline-block elements wrapper div.

Comment: A space that has zero `font-size` is generally zero width.

Comment: You can also check this [source](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to go with float for these scenarios.

```
.main-bar, .side-bar{
    margin:0; padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border:none;
    background:#CCC
    float: left;
}
.main-bar{width: 70%}
.side-bar{width: 30%}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 .main-bar, .side-bar{
            position: relative;
            margin:0; padding: 0;
            outline: 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border:0;
            background:#CCC;
            float:left;
        }
```

Inline elements:

1. respect left & right margins and padding, but not top & bottom
2. cannot have a width and height set
3. allow other elements to sit to
       their left and right.

Block elements:

1. respect all of those
2. force a line break after the block element.