# CSS crazyness inline-block unremovable margin

Tags: html, css

Check the code below :

Why is there spaces beetwen the divs ? How can I remove them (without using float) ?

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px;
  /*float: left;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="section">a</div>
  <div class="section">b</div>
  <div class="section">c</div>
  <div class="section">d</div>
  <div class="section">e</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check my previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26882886/3834042

Comment: Phew! There are so many dupes! I can't believe this question could be asked so many times and yet draw many votes on each of those!!

Comment: use  margin-right: -4px;

Comment: @moderator it is a duplicate question indeed. Thank you for deleting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer is @emmanuel one (see question comment).
Even if there is no text, spaces beetwen divs does count.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px;
  /*float: left;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="section">a</div><!--
  --><div class="section">b</div><!--
  --><div class="section">c</div><!--
  --><div class="section">d</div><!--
  --><div class="section">e</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to solve this. My favourite is:

```
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  letter-spacing: -0.32em;
}

.section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px;
  /*float: left;*/
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdysnk7w/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the divs are spaced by a line break, which is interpreted as a space in the resulting HTML.

Try changing it to:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="section">a</div><div class="section">b</div><div class="section">c</div><div class="section">d</div><div class="section">e</div>
</div>
```

If you want to preserve some white space, simply include it in comments:

```
<div id="container">
     <div class="section">a</div><!--
  --><div class="section">b</div><!--
  --><div class="section">c</div><!--
  --><div class="section">d</div><!--
  --><div class="section">e</div>
</div>
```

Lastly, you can change `display: inline-block`; to `display: table-cell`, but then you will need to re-work the section width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="section">a</div><div class="section">b</div><div class="section">c</div><div class="section">d</div><div class="section">e</div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z3mdcbcx/)**